# granting a permission that didn't exist on installation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have two separate apps, A and B.
A exposes a permission and B uses it for Content Provider READ Access.
If A is installed first then when B is installed the permission is granted and all is peachy.
However, if B is installed first it will not have the permission when A is installed.

Is there a common solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Provide an intent as an API for B to call A with a return. Otherwise if it fails, then show an error for B and take the user to the play store where they can install A.  When B returns from the play store call A's intent again. That would make it so that if A isn't present, B will not do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Adamoutler. If I understand correctly, your solution implies giving up the custom permission altogether (which is a valid argument considering the platform limitations). If so, why not just allow read access to all via the ContentProvider?

Answer (score 1):

I read about that issue some time ago and ATM this is a problem that cannot be solved without hacks. Here is also that problem pointed https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/kCJN1rj5pMo I would trust Dianne Hackborn answer about granting permissions.